# Insert Null in column 'A' based on index values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list with index numbers 'l1' and I want to replace values in the column 'A' with NaN based on those index numbers

Current Data

```
Index                A
0        Reviewer: Newbie | 35-44 on Treatment for 1 
1        Reviewer: 45-54 on Treatment for less than 1 
2        Reviewer: Ocetech| 65-74 Male on Treatment 
3        Reviewer: virleo| 55-64 Female on Treatment 
4        Reviewer: Diane perrin| 65-74 on Treatment for
```

l1 = [ 1 , 3, 4]

Expected Output

```
Index                A
0        Reviewer: Newbie | 35-44 on Treatment for 1 
1        NaN 
2        Reviewer: Ocetech| 65-74 Male on Treatment 
3        NaN
4        NaN
```

Comment: Use `df.loc[l1,'A'] = np.nan`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.loc` for locating the index in l1 in your dataframe and then assign `np.nan` like:

```
import numpy as np
df.loc[l1,'A'] = np.nan
```

Answer (score 1):

Just to the details after reproducing your DataFrame..

Import numpy as well to set the `Nan` values to the desired Index..

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Your DataFrame:

```
$ df
                                                A
0     Reviewer: Newbie | 35-44 on Treatment for 1
1    Reviewer: 45-54 on Treatment for less than 1
2      Reviewer: Ocetech| 65-74 Male on Treatment
3     Reviewer: virleo| 55-64 Female on Treatment
4  Reviewer: Diane perrin| 65-74 on Treatment for
```

Your Indexed List:

```
$ l1
[1, 3, 4]
```

Based  On `loc` For a column `A` to set the Index to `Nan`  using Numpy ..

```
df.loc[l1,'A'] = np.nan
```

Result:

```
print(df)
                                             A
0  Reviewer: Newbie | 35-44 on Treatment for 1
1                                          NaN
2   Reviewer: Ocetech| 65-74 Male on Treatment
3                                          NaN
4                                          NaN
```

Just a side note if you don't have a long list of Index to be replace to `NaN`, you can directly specify them rather passing a list Index.

```
$ df.loc[[1,3,4],'A'] = np.nan
$ print(df)
                                             A
0  Reviewer: Newbie | 35-44 on Treatment for 1
1                                          NaN
2   Reviewer: Ocetech| 65-74 Male on Treatment
3                                          NaN
4                                          NaN
```

## Another way around:

```
$ df.rename(index={1:np.nan, 3:np.nan, 4:np.nan}, inplace=True)
```